# Run Nohup while SFTP

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

- I have huge file to transfer from one server to another server.
- Im using sftp mode and using command eg: "sftp>put file.txt"
- Question : how do i run the command in  nohup so that i can close my sftp session without killing the transfer process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "put file.txt" | sftp -b - servername &
```

If I understand you correctly.

Comment: where's the `nohup` part? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
  echo "put file.txt" | sftp username@hostname
  ctrl-z
  bg
  disown
```

Comment: in your linux terminal

Comment: can provide some example on how to write in shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Nohup doesn't work with sftp, if you close the shell , it will kill the process.
Just put the command to run in crontab, process will continue, even you close all shells.